# How can I find the intersection of two lines more efficiently? (nested for loops in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, intersection

I need to find the intersection point of two data sets, as illustrated here:

[image: Data plot]

I have used the nested loops below to achieve this, but it takes impractically long to run for a dataframe with more (~1000) rows. How can I do this more efficiently?

For clarity, here is a screenshot of the CSV used in the example (len=20):

[image: CSV]

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Less_Data.csv")

#Intersection of line A (points 1 & 2) and line B (points 3 & 4)
def findIntersection(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4):
    px= (( (x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4) )
      / ( (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4) ))
    py= (( (x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4) )
      / ( (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4) ))
    return [px, py]

#Find intersection of two series
intersections = {}
error_x = {}
error_y = {}
count = 0
print('All intersections found:')

for i in range(len(data)):
    i_storage_modulus = data.iloc[i]['Storage_Modulus_Pa']
    i_storage_stress = data.iloc[i]['Storage_Oscillation_Stress_Pa']
    for j in range(len(data)):
        j_storage_modulus = data.iloc[j]['Storage_Modulus_Pa']
        j_storage_stress = data.iloc[j]['Storage_Oscillation_Stress_Pa']
        if i == j + 1:
            for k in range(len(data)):
                k_loss_stress = data.iloc[k]['Loss_Oscillation_Stress_Pa']
                k_loss_modulus = data.iloc[k]['Loss_Modulus_Pa']
                for l in range(len(data)):
                    l_loss_stress = data.iloc[l]['Loss_Oscillation_Stress_Pa']
                    l_loss_modulus = data.iloc[l]['Loss_Modulus_Pa']
                    if k == l + 1:
                        if (max(k_loss_modulus, l_loss_modulus)
    <= min(i_storage_modulus, j_storage_modulus)):
                            continue
                        else:
                            sample_intersect = findIntersection(i_storage_stress,
                                                 i_storage_modulus,
                                                 j_storage_stress,
                                                 j_storage_modulus,
                                                 k_loss_stress,
                                                 k_loss_modulus,
                                                 l_loss_stress,
                                                 l_loss_modulus)
                            if (min(i_storage_stress, j_storage_stress)
              <= sample_intersect[0]
              <= max(i_storage_stress, j_storage_stress)):
                                if (min(k_loss_stress, l_loss_stress)
               <= sample_intersect[0]
               <= max(k_loss_stress, l_loss_stress)):
                                      print(sample_intersect)
                                      intersections[count] = sample_intersect
                                      error_x[count] = ([i_storage_stress,
                                                 j_storage_stress,
                                                 k_loss_stress,
                                                 l_loss_stress])
                                      error_y[count] = ([i_storage_modulus,
                                                 j_storage_modulus,
                                                 k_loss_modulus,
                                                 l_loss_modulus])
                                      count += 1

#Determine error bars
min_x_poss = []
max_x_poss = []
for i in error_x[0]:
    if i < intersections[0][0]:
        min_x_poss.append(i)
    if i > intersections[0][0]:
        max_x_poss.append(i)
x_error = (min(max_x_poss) - max(min_x_poss)) / 2

min_y_poss = []
max_y_poss = []
for i in error_y[0]:
    if i < intersections[0][1]:
        min_y_poss.append(i)
    if i > intersections[0][1]:
        max_y_poss.append(i)
y_error = (min(max_y_poss) - max(min_y_poss)) / 2

#Print results
print('\n', 'Yield Stress: ' + str(int(intersections[0][0])) + ' ± ' +
      str(int(x_error)) + ' Pa (' +
      str(int(x_error*100/intersections[0][0]))+'%)')
print('\n', 'Yield Modulus: ' + str(int(intersections[0][1])) + ' ± ' +
      str(int(y_error)) + ' Pa (' +
      str(int(y_error*100/intersections[0][1]))+'%)')
```

Comment: one simple way to reduce the number of intersection tests would be to only test intersection if the rectangle bounding boxes for each line segment (x1,y1),(x2,y2) overlap

Comment: so if rectangle (min(Xi,Xj),min(Yi,Yj)-(max(Xi,Xj),max(Yi,Yj)) overlaps with (min(Xk,Xl),min(Yk,Yl)-(max(Xk,Xl),max(Yk,Yl)) then do the expensive intersection test.

Comment: further optimisation (well, reduction of the number of comparisons needed) should be possible - do a first pass filtering both datasets: if the rectangle bounding box for a line segment is outside the current bbox for the complete other dataset then drop it from the comparison sets.The aim with this is to ensure you don't repeatedly test a segment against segments which it can never overlap, by removing it in one test before the full comparison proceeds. As you remove a segment recalculate the bounding box for that dataset, and iterate until a pass has been completed without removing a segment

Comment: Thanks! I have tried adding a couple of conditions to pass before doing the intersection test, but this one sounds cheap and effective!

Comment: So there's no way of doing this without using laborious for-loops?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get run time down to 2 minutes by excluding rows with empty cells, and using the following code to find overlapping rectangles:

`def overlap(y1,y2,y3,y4):
 if max(y1,y2) < min(y3,y4):
  return False
 elif max(y3,y4) < min(y1,y2):
  return False
 else:
  return True`

Comment: :-) What speed up is that - any idea how long it took originally?

Comment: At least 10 minutes to analyse the same data. I didn't let it finish before, because it takes around 10 minutes to analyse the data manually.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a new function `y = (Storage Modulus - Loss Modulus) vs Oscillation Stress`?  The point of intersection is where `y` changes sign from positive to negative.  The secant method should find this point in a few iterations.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method

Comment: Thanks, I did initially try to tackle it by applying scipy.interpolate.interp1d to the data, but I ran into a couple of issues:

1) Sometimes my data isn't monotonic, so it required a fairly chunky function to chop it up into sections.

2) I have no idea how to do algebra with interp1d outputs. I couldn't seem to do interp1d(a) - interp1d(b).